# How to detect that app is running on beta version of Android?

Tags: android

As title says, is it possible to detect via code that app is running under beta/dev preview version of Android (like Q now and P in the past)?

I couldn't find any dependable solution (I've found `PREVIEW_SDK_INT` trick, but it is 0 for the last two Q betas, so it does not seem to be reliable solution).

Comment: I suspect that there is none, other than determining it manually. For example, right now, you know that a device running API Level 29 is a beta, because Q has not shipped yet. So, you treat all API Level 29 devices as being beta until Q starts shipping, then you upgrade your app to treat API Level 29 as non-beta.

Answer (score 0):

If this works for you : You can find if the device's current API is a development build or not using(For current device's API level >= 4) :

```
String androidDs = getAndroidVersion(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
```

The String result will have the code for example 28 for Pie. If the current development version is running, it will return 10000. You can use this result.

[Build.VERSION_CODES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work - it returns 29 on recent Q betas. I checked all android.os.Build class fields and they all have values like on a normal, stable release of Android as of recent betas (5 and 6).